# Prevent ReSharper 9.1 from auto-inserting <> angle brackets when autocompleting generic type

Tags: c#, resharper, intellisense, code-completion, resharper-9.1

I don't like it when tools auto-insert brackets, parentheses, quotes, etc. and have disabled these features in Resharper 9.1. However, there's still one case where it insists on doing it. If I type (e.g.) `IEnumerable`, it automatically inserts a pair of angle brackets and positions the cursor between them as soon as I type the final "e". This also happens if I hit an auto-completion key like tab before typing the entire word. This forces me to move my hands off the home position in order to arrow-key over the `>` (if I type `>` manually, I end up with two of them). Is there any way to prevent the angle brackets from being inserted in this case?

Interestingly, if I *enable* "Auto-insert pair brackets, parentheses, and quotes," I get the same behavior, but when I type `>`, it just jumps the cursor over the existing `>` instead of inserting another one.